# Moving a window with WinMove is very slow

Tags: performance, window, autohotkey

I am trying to implement a sort of window-docking function in AutoHotkey and am having trouble with performance of moving windows with `WinMove`.

In my message handler, I detect if the window being moved has any dependents and move them as necessary. The problem is that moving the dockee with `WinMove` causes a very slow and jerky drag movement. Curiously, the CPU load does *not* go up, so it is not caused by a bad loop or some such.

If I use the `Gui,Show` command instead, it results in a nice, fluid motion, but then if the docked window is closed and it’s parent is moved, the dockee reappears as a thin ~5x10-pixel window. I tried using the `hide` option for the `Gui` command, as well as specifically adding a call to `Gui, Destroy` in the windows’ close-handlers, but neither helped. Further, using the `Gui` command means that not only is it much messier, but I have to store the Gui number in addition to the handle, which is not ideal.

```
; Works and leaves closed windows closed, but is very slow
WinMove, ahk_id %dHWND%,, dX, dY

; This works and is fast, but requires storing the GUI # and closed windows reappear
Gui, % (Dock[dHWND, "gui"] ? Dock[dHWND, "gui"] . ":" : "") . "Show", % "hide na x" . dX " y" . dY
```

Does anyone know why `WinMove` is so slow and how to fix it? (I would also consider the `Gui` command if it can be fixed to not re-show closed windows.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SetWinDelay, -1` should solve your problem.

"A short delay (sleep) is done automatically after every windowing command" because of this which default to 100ms.

Comment: Perfect. I keep forgetting about that. Thanks three million.